# Error creating shaded jar: Error in ASM processing class kotlin/collections/ArraysKt___ArraysKt.class: UTF8 string too large

Tags: maven, kotlin, jar, jvm, maven-shade-plugin

I am trying to upgrade kotlin version of shading project but i am getting below issue when i upgrade to kotlin 1.5.30:

`org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.4.1:shade (default) on project authentication-downstream-clients-shaded: Error creating shaded jar: Problem shading JAR /Users/aagrawal/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.5.30/kotlin-stdlib-1.5.30.jar entry kotlin/collections/ArraysKt___ArraysKt.class: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error in ASM processing class kotlin/collections/ArraysKt___ArraysKt.class`
Same is not happening in case of kotilin 1.3.31

I have tried several versions of `maven-shade-plugin`, tried to exclude this specific class by using

```
        <filters>
          <filter>
            <artifact>kotlin-stdlib</artifact>
            <includes>
              <include>kotlin/collections/**</include>
            </includes>
          </filter>
        </filters>
```

But getting same exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>asm:*</exclude> <!-- Exclude current ASM version -->
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
                <relocations>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>org.objectweb.asm</pattern> <!-- Relocate to new ASM version -->
                        <shadedPattern>com.example.asm</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                </relocations>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId> <!-- Add desired ASM version -->
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                    <version>9.4</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```